# Count the number of raise per group and per entity_id from a history table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL structure :

```
CREATE TABLE history(
  entity_id INT,
  raise_number INT,
  assignedtogroup INT,
  time BIGINT
);
INSERT INTO history (entity_id, raise_number, assignedtogroup, time)
VALUES
(452885, 0, 435189, 1622817568259),
(452885, NULL, 435189, 1622817568259),
(452885, 1, NULL, 1623082677268),
(452885, NULL, 10086, 1623233125267),
(452885, NULL, 10086, 1623233125267),
...
```

I need to count the number of raise per group and by entity_id. For now, I'm able to retreive the number of raise by group.

```
WITH ForwardFilled(filledgroup, raise_number) AS (
    SELECT MAX(assignedtogroup) OVER (PARTITION BY grp), raise_number
    FROM(
        SELECT raise_number, assignedtogroup,
              COUNT(assignedtogroup) OVER (ORDER BY time ASC)
        FROM history
    ) T(raise_number, assignedtogroup, grp)
)
SELECT filledGroup, COUNT(raise_number)
FROM ForwardFilled
WHERE raise_number <> 0
GROUP BY filledGroup
ORDER BY filledgroup
```

Output :

| filledgroup | count |
| --- | --- |
| 10086 | 6 |
| 435113 | 15 |
| 435114 | 5 |
| 435134 | 4 |
| 435144 | 2 |
| 435146 | 14 |
| 435156 | 8 |
| 435160 | 28 |
| 435188 | 15 |
| 435204 | 7 |

How can I retrieve the number of raises per `entity_id` and per `assignedtogroup`?

Table need to have the following column :

| entity_id | filledgroup | count |
| --- | --- | --- |

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2w8RxBK4p8xL8a5LbLzsBZ/0

Comment: Hi. Did you try `group by entity_id, assignedtogroup`? Your question sounds exactly like this operator works, it helps to group the values by `group` and `per entity_id`. Otherwise, I don't understand your question.

Comment: You are currently using MAX(assignedtogroup). Is entity determined by MAX(assignedtogroup) also? I.e. are there other conditions to cater for?

Comment: There is no more condition to add, I only need a grouping by entity_id and filledgroup